# Odd Microwave Oven Display Malfunction:

Tags: led, led-driver, led-matrix

My Sharp Carousel microwave oven (model R-303CW) display has been flickering off & on recently (mostly it appears to be off).  When it appears to be off, the display characters are actually very dimly lit.  If I shine a light onto the display at the right angle, the correct display characters (i.e. clock, timer, etc) appear to be almost as bright as when the display is working properly.  The display output should appear the color & brightness of the last image below (which is not of my actual unit).  I've included a few (hopefully useful) pics below.

Is the cause of the problem some kind of LED back-lighting malfunction??  If yes, how is that implemented to shine light onto the reflector that is behind the display lens?  The display looks like a piece of glass with the LCD characters produced inside the glass.  There is a florescent green paper strip behind the display lens which imparts the yellow-green color that the characters usually appears as when the display is working properly.

I did not see any obvious problem when viewing the circuit card.  If anyone knows what the cause of this problem is, please let me know.  I thought the problem might be the ribbon cable (i.e. the upper ribbon cable in img 2) that connects the LCD display & to the display control circuit card; however, after pressing firmly along the ribbon cable on both ends while it was powered, there was no noticeable difference in the display output.  Thanks in advance for your consideration & thoughts!

[image: Display & Ctrl Panel][image: Display xit bd][image]

A schematic can be viewed [here](http://www.manualslib.com/manual/692328/Sharp-R-303cw.html?page=10#manual).

Comment: Which Stack Exchange forum would this ideally be submitted to?  I checked the list & couldn't find another SE group that I thought would be better than this one.  Pls advise.

Comment: it sounds like the backlight for the display is failing.  backlight could be EL (electroluminescent) instead of LED.   EL is a sheet that lights up with about 100V on it, LED usually uses some sort of light pipe to direct light from the side to the back of the display.

Comment: @Jasen - thanks for that information.  It turns out the display is some kind of LCD, actually.

Comment: yeah, looks like LCD with a backlight - LCD doesn't glow by itself.

Comment: @Jasen - I examined the display & controller more closely today.  The LCD is actually a thin layer film that is attached to a piece of glass.  There are 4 small LEDs on the opposite side of the display controller card that light occasionally for short periods of time.  Do you think the caps on the back of the card are possibly failing & that is why the LEDs only remain lit for short periods of time?  The only other components that I see on the card look like small surface mount resistors, caps, & the processor (covered in black epoxy in the photo).

Comment: could be, seems more likely to be a bad wire-bond in one of the leds.  measure the voltage across each led when working and when not working.  that may give some indication of the location of the fault.